# FIFO buffer in the ATmega328P

Tags: microcontroller, uart, datasheet, atmega328p, register

I have a problem in understanding the working of the FIFO buffer. The diagram of the USART in the datasheet does not mention the FIFO buffer, and it just gives the UDR register which acts as a transmit buffer.

But in the receiver side, it's written that the data flags are present in the FIFO buffer. I do not know what they mean by the FIFO buffer here. In the same page in the coding section they are extracting the flags from the `UCSRnA` register. Does this mean they are referring to the `UCSRnA` register as Buffer? But this seems to be invalid to me. Kindly explain this.

[image]

The code is:

[image]

[ATmega328P datasheet](https://ww1.microchip.com/downloads/en/DeviceDoc/Atmel-7810-Automotive-Microcontrollers-ATmega328P_Datasheet.pdf)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are more details on the FIFO in the section:

```
19.10.1 UDRn – USART I/O Data Register n
```

`UDRn` serves 2 purposes.  From a software perspective, this register address is both the transmit data register and the receive data register.  A software write to this register will cause data to be transmitted, whereas a read of the register will  return the received data.  This register does not act only as the transmit buffer.

The `UCSRnA` register is not the receive buffer.  It is the "USART Control and Status Register n A".  It does not contain the received data value.

This is what it says about the FIFO:

> The receive buffer consists of a two level FIFO. The FIFO will change
> its state whenever the receive buffer is accessed.

The FIFO only stores up to 2 received data words.  Having a small FIFO allows software a little time to respond to a receive interrupt.  It is reasonable that this FIFO detail was omitted from a high-level block diagram.

The status register has a `UDREn` bit, but that is only for data **transmit**, not receive.  When the bit is set to 1, it indicates that the **transmit** buffer is ready to be written by software with new data to be transmitted.  When the bit is 1, the **transmit** buffer is empty.

Comment: How does the UDR get empty. Considering the receiver end How does the UDR get empty. When I transfer data to the UDR. The contents of the UDR are copied to the shift register. Does that make the URD empty?? Or it is emptied as the shift register is emptied or data shifted??

Comment: @MuhammadHamzaFarooq:  That is all described in the UDRn section I mentioned. Re-read the section a few times... it often takes me a while to fully absorb the information.

Comment: Ive read that section but it doesnt tell when the UDRn gets emptied. I am assuming it automatically gets emptied when the shiftregisters transmits all the data.

Comment: @MuhammadHamzaFarooq: I updated the answer.  Your original question was only about RX, but your question in the comment is now about TX.  It is confusing that the UART uses the same register for both directions.  All the information you need to know about operating the device is in the datasheet.  Implementation details that you do not need to know are omitted.